# Align post titles in Blogger Dynamic View template

Tags: blogger, blogger-dynamic-views

I'd like to left-align post titles for a Dynamic View template in Blogger. I've tried adding custom CSS through the Template Designer screen, and also adding custom CSS through the Edit HTML button on the Template screen.

Here's a CSS rule I've tried:

```
.title .entry-title {
text-align:left !important;
}
```

So far, nothing works. I'm able to change alignment for non-Dynamic View templates, but not for Dynamic Views.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
.article .article-header .title {
  text-align: left;
}
```